# two sounds play on one button in swift

Tags: xcode, audio, swift3

i have three buttons and each are supposed to play a different sound which they do. My problem is that the second button once clicked also plays the first sound. 
is there something i could do to fix this?

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    do {
    audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "OhNo", ofType: "mp3")! ))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }

    do {
        audioPlayer1 =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep2", ofType: "mp3")! ))
        audioPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
    }
    catch{
        print(error)

    }

    do {
        audioPlayer2 =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep10", ofType: "mp3")! ))
        audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()
        }
        catch{
            print(error)

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



       @IBAction func catSound(_ sender: UIButton) { 
    audioPlayer.play()

}

        @IBAction func beep(_ sender: UIButton) {

        audioPlayer1.play()

        }

    @IBAction func beep10(_ sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer2.play()

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your storyboard and make sure you haven't connected the second button to both the first and second `@IBAction`.

Do this buy right-clicking on the second button in the storyboard. On the `Touch up Inside`-event there should be only one connection, the `beep`. On the one where it says `catSound`, click the little x to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try stopping the other AudioPlayers?

```
 @IBAction func beep(_ sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer2.stop()
    audioPlayer1.play()

    }
```